# Unable to push commits from a git submodule?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I have a simple project that has one submodule.

```
$ git submodule
 964737623a362f6303e87ec41f2c7090c8c2c093 lib/mongodb-php-odm (heads/master-1-g9647376)
```

I have made changes to that submodule and committed them, but cannot push them to github.

```
$ cd lib/mongodb-php-odm
$ git branch
* (no branch)
  master
$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:colinmollenhour/mongodb-php-odm.git
$ git ls-remote .
964737623a362f6303e87ec41f2c7090c8c2c093    HEAD
6f5f91eff9b1854faa30608f335aee92aa7532eb    refs/heads/master
6f5f91eff9b1854faa30608f335aee92aa7532eb    refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
6f5f91eff9b1854faa30608f335aee92aa7532eb    refs/remotes/origin/master
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

I don't understand why it says "Everything up-to-date" because the 964737 commit has not been pushed to github. It is likely I did something wrong, but I have no idea what that would be..

How do I push the latest commit in this submodule to github?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that you committed to no branch, i.e. your commit isn't part of any branch. Create a branch where you're standing, then launch gitk to compare to master, then cherry-pick or rebase as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, that got me going in the right direction. Here are the steps I took exactly, which worked like a charm. Looks pretty simple now...  git checkout -b temp; git checkout master; git merge temp; git branch -d temp; git push origin master;

Comment: This is generally the state a submodule will be in. When a git submodule command checks out a given commit, it does so in detached HEAD mode (no branch checked out, just the specific commit).

Comment: [what to do if you commit to no branch](http://edspencer.net/2009/10/git-what-to-do-if-you-commit-to-no-branch.html) is a good article for solving this situation.

Comment: @ColinM, I think you should move your comment to an answer because it is the complete solution, That helped me solve the exact same problem! Thanks

Answer (score 9):

> @ColinM, I think you should move your comment to an answer because it is the complete solution, That helped me solve the exact same problem! Thanks –  Juan Carlos Moreno

I'll do that here.

As Scheffer said, you're on a "HEAD-less" commit. As ColinM said, you can merge that commit back to *master* like this:

```
cd lib/mongodb-php-odm
git checkout master
git merge HEAD@{1}
git push origin master
```

EDIT: Using `HEAD@{1}` instead of a temporary branch or tag is simpler since there is no cleanup required. The expression `HEAD@{1}` means the HEAD's previous value which in this case would be the new commit on the headless branch.

Comment: Please include some explanation of what you're doing and how it solves the problem.

Comment: @Barmar, git-submodules will checkout a specific commit, not a branch, so it leaves sub-repos with "detached heads". These steps (suggested by ColinM) merge the current commit into the `master` branch before pushing.